# PL/SQL Regular Expression dash and brackets in the Matching Character List

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql, regex-negation

My problem is that I need to remove all invalid characters from a column, but the dash and brackets characters are valid ones.

as so far my sql is:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(column_name, '[^][-0-9a-z]' , '') FROM table_name;
```

but this doesn't include the dash character.

and:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(column_name, '[^-][0-9a-z]' , '') FROM table_name;
```

this isn't good either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 solutions for this:

1, use one of them at start and other at the end of the Matching Character List:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(column_name, '[^][0-9a-z-]' , '') FROM table_name;
```

2, using the POSIX Collating Element Operator `[.character.]`:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(column_name, '[^[.].][.[.][.-.]0-9a-z]' , '') FROM table_name;
```